# Is there any alternative to L-BFGS-B algorithm for hyperparameter optimization in Scikit learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, hyperparameter, hyperparameter-tuning

The Gaussian process regression can be computed in scikit learn using an object of class GaussianProcessRegressor as:

```
 gp= GaussianProcessRegressor(alpha=1e-10, copy_X_train=True,
    kernel=1**2 + Matern(length_scale=2, nu=1.5) + WhiteKernel(noise_level=1),
    n_restarts_optimizer=0, normalize_y=False,
    optimizer='fmin_l_bfgs_b', random_state=None)
```

Here, we see that the L-BFGS-B algorithm has been used to optimize the hyperparameters. Is there any alternative (for example trust-region-reflective algorithm) to this algorithm available in sklearn?

**EDIT**: [It](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/optimize.html) provides some Constrained multivariate methods for optimization. Is there such functions available for other methods like trust-region-reflective algorithm and swarm intelligence (eg. Firefly algorithm)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scikit-learn package has a limited selection of optimizers. The [scipy](https://www.scipy.org/) package has many more [optimitizers](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html), including [trust-region-reflective algorithm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy.optimize.least_squares). You would have to use another [third party package for Firefly algorithm](https://github.com/7ossam81/EvoloPy).